# Utilizando PYQT5 Al hacer Click sobre Etiqueta No se ejecuta la funcion

Tags: python, pyqt5

Genere una acción clcik a un Label con un pixmap asociado, al hacer click sobre la etiqueta solo visualizo el QMessageBox que coloque como referencia, la función que cambia el color al pixmap no hace nada. Les dejo el codigo y ojala puedan ayudarme.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, pyqtSignal)

import LabelClickeable

from LabelClickeable import QLabelClickable



class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 Cambio de Colores con Clic '
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 720
        self.initUI()



    def CambioColor(self,MiPixmap):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Correcto", "Cambio de Color",   QMessageBox.Ok)
        Peda1 = QLabel(self)
        p = QPainter(MiPixmap)
        pix=QPixmap(MiPixmap)
        mask1 = pix.createMaskFromColor(QColor(221,221,221), Qt.MaskOutColor)
        p.setPen(QColor(120, 255, 255))
        p.drawPixmap(pix.rect(), mask1, mask1.rect())
        p.end()
        Peda1.setPixmap(pix)




    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        Peda1 = QLabel(self)

        pixmapPed1 = QPixmap('C:\\python\\proyectos\\pyqt5\\MainWindow\\MainWindow\\images\\peda1n.png')


        Peda1 = QLabelClickable(self)

        Peda1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.CambioColor(pixmapPed1))

        Peda1.move(300,100)



        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

No es que la función no haga nada, es que asigna el `Qpixmap` a una etiqueta creada localmente en el propio método y que nada tiene que ver con tu etiqueta original. El widget `Peda1` que creas `initUI` y que muestras al iniciar la app es un widget diferente a la instancia de `QLabel` que creas en el método `CambioColor` (`Peda1 = QLabel(self)`).

A esto hay que añadirle que la etiqueta creada al llamar a `CambioColor` **no se muestra** porque no llamas a su método `show` explícitamente. La primera (la creada en `initUI`) se muestra porque Qt se asegura de mostrar todos los widgets hijos cuando se llama al método `show` del padre, pero la segunda etiqueta es creada después de la inicialización del padre por o que esto no ocurre.

Si quieres modificar esa misma etiqueta asigna su referencia a un atributo de instancia mediante el cual podrás acceder al widget desde cualquier método de instancia como es `CambioColor`.

Un ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen, QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

#import LabelClickeable
#from LabelClickeable import QLabelClickable

class QLabelClickable(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 Cambio de Colores con Clic '
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 720
        self.pixmap_ped1 = None
        self.peda1_lbl = None
        self.initUI()


    def cambio_color(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Correcto", "Cambio de Color", QMessageBox.Ok)

        pix = self.pixmap_ped1.copy()
        mask = pix.createMaskFromColor(QColor(0, 0, 0), Qt.MaskOutColor)

        p = QPainter(pix)
        p.setPen(QColor(115, 0, 153))
        p.drawPixmap(pix.rect(), mask, mask.rect())
        p.end()
        self.peda1_lbl.setPixmap(pix)


    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.pixmap_ped1 = QPixmap('image.png')
        self.peda1_lbl = QLabelClickable(self)
        self.peda1_lbl.clicked.connect(self.cambio_color)
        self.peda1_lbl.move(140, 170)
        self.peda1_lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap_ped1)
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si vas a reutilizar el pixmap original o no en la app, he optado por asignarlo a un atributo de instancia también y usar una copia del mismo al cambiar al aplicar la máscara, pero puedes cargarlo en el método desde disco de nuevo, modificarlo en vez de crear una copia, etc. Esta es la imagen por si se quiere reproducir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solucionado el problema!!!!, Me fue muy util tu respuesta